# Can I have bootstrap columns go to next row two by two on smaller screens?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsiveness

I have this html code:

```
        <div class="row fluid">
            <div class="col-md-3 clearfix">
                    <img src="img">
                    <div class="img-text"> 
                        Tekst fdskfjsdghdfn ufghdg ufdhs gdfksjhg 
                      jfdksgbfjdsk gfd jgbdfjhg dfkjhg fidughdf kjvhdf ugdfh 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 clearfix">
                    <img src="img">
                    <div class="img-text"> 
                        Tekst fdskfjsdghdfn ufghdg ufdhs gdfksjhg 
                      jfdksgbfjdsk gfd jgbdfjhg dfkjhg fidughdf kjvhdf ugdfh 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 clearfix">
                    <img src="img">
                    <div class="img-text"> 
                        Tekst fdskfjsdghdfn ufghdg ufdhs gdfksjhg 
                      jfdksgbfjdsk gfd jgbdfjhg dfkjhg fidughdf kjvhdf ugdfh 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 clearfix">
                    <img src="img">
                    <div class="img-text"> 
                        Tekst fdskfjsdghdfn ufghdg ufdhs gdfksjhg 
                      jfdksgbfjdsk gfd jgbdfjhg dfkjhg fidughdf kjvhdf ugdfh 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I would like these columns to go to new rows two by two, except on mobile phones. Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: You mean 2 col in each row for any device without Mobile phones?

Comment: Almost. I want 4 in a row, and as the screen gets smaller, to be two in a row, and then one column in each row.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3>
        Content
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3>
        Content
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3>
        Content
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3>
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

If I understand correctly you want output

```
1 2 3 4
```

on medium screen size,

```
1 2
3 4
```

on small screen size and

```
1
2
3
4
```

on extra small screen size

You can accomplish that using `col-xs-12`, `col-sm-6` and `col-md-3` classes like code below.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            2
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            3
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            4
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dejanmarolt/kj5g0zjr/).

Answer (score 1):

Here, look at this. You'll have 4 columns for PC, 2 columns for small devices, and 1 column for extra small devices like mobile.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <div class="row fluid">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 clearfix">
                    <img src="img">
                    <div class="img-text"> 
                        Tekst fdskfjsdghdfn ufghdg ufdhs gdfksjhg 
                      jfdksgbfjdsk gfd jgbdfjhg dfkjhg fidughdf kjvhdf ugdfh 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 clearfix">
                    <img src="img">
                    <div class="img-text"> 
                        Tekst fdskfjsdghdfn ufghdg ufdhs gdfksjhg 
                      jfdksgbfjdsk gfd jgbdfjhg dfkjhg fidughdf kjvhdf ugdfh 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 clearfix">
                    <img src="img">
                    <div class="img-text"> 
                        Tekst fdskfjsdghdfn ufghdg ufdhs gdfksjhg 
                      jfdksgbfjdsk gfd jgbdfjhg dfkjhg fidughdf kjvhdf ugdfh 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 clearfix">
                    <img src="img">
                    <div class="img-text"> 
                        Tekst fdskfjsdghdfn ufghdg ufdhs gdfksjhg 
                      jfdksgbfjdsk gfd jgbdfjhg dfkjhg fidughdf kjvhdf ugdfh 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

For better understanding how this works, look at bootstrap's documentation - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed-complete